# Sync Framework how to Determine Rows that has been Synchronized to SQL SERVER Database

Tags: vb.net

I want to filter the SQL Compact Database to get rows that as been synchronized to the SQL SEVER Using sync framework can any one give me an hint on how to get this done. I will prefer a sample code in VB.NET

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to determine the pending rows (rows that aren't synchronized yet):

```
Dim provider = DirectCast(SyncAgent.LocalProvider, SqlCeClientSyncProvider)
Dim testBeforeSync = provider.GetChanges("tblBarCodeScanning")
'contains all the pending rows, all the other rows are already synchronized and can be deleted!
Dim table = testBeforeSync.DataSet.Tables(0)
```